# Repeat prompt until condition

Tags: javascript

Cant manage to ask an user to input text again in case his text is empty, this is my code:

```
var userText = prompt("Introduce some words.");
var counter = 0;
while(counter!=0){
    if(userText){
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Im not null";
        counter = 1;
    }else{
        userText = prompt("Introduce some words.");
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Im null";
    }
}
```

Even if i introduce a long word or simply press enter OK or Cancel wont do anything. It must ask user for some words again in case they press either OK or Cancel...

Comment: That while loop will never get hit because it's always 0

Comment: Your `while` loop never runs.  `0 != 0` is false.

Comment: Step through your code line-by-line with a "debugger", which is a tool used for "debugging".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
var userText = "";

while (userText.length < 1) {
    userText = prompt("Introduce some words.");
}

document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Im not null";
```

This will simply keep checking to make sure that the use has entered something in the prompt, before it moves on.  For better results, you might also consider introducing some whitespace stripping or regex patterns, to make sure that the entered values are not simply spaces.

Answer (score 1):

That while loop will never get hit because it's always 0.

Somewhere in your code, before the while loop, you need to set the counter so that it is not equal to 0 so that the while loop can execute